# How to create optimal solenoid actuator

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, coil, solenoid, electromagnetic

I would like to create a solenoid like this one:

[image: Solenoid actuator image]

It should be powered by 5V and of course I want it to take as little current as possible. I know it will probably still take a current of around 0.75, 0.8, or 1A, but the lower the better. At the same time it must be strong. Say it has to lift up an object of 40 grams (0.088 lbs) against gravity.

As far as I know there are two things that make it stronger:

- Higher current.
- More windings.

Since I want to limit the current, I have to give it more copper windings.
I'm not familiar with solenoids and electric fields.
Therefore I have some questions:

1. How to determine (approximately) how many copper windings I need for a predetermined current (formula/example) to make it the strong as I would like (lifting 40 grams)?
2. What can I do to make it hot as slowly as possible?
3. They say it will be stronger if you cover it with a metal housing to keep the magnetic field inside. Can the housing be of any metal (like aluminium, stainless steel, or tin metal), Should it be of some specific metal, or doesn't it matter that much and is it already beneficial to have a metal housing at all?
4. Any other tips for building this thing yourself?

Comment: [Solenoid force calculator](https://daycounter.com/Calculators/Magnets/Solenoid-Force-Calculator.phtml). You should really use google first!!!

Comment: The metal frame needs to be a cold rolled iron  material. This would be a soft iron as opposed to some hardened material. The DC current of the coil will be limited by the total DC resistance of the length of wire that you use to create the coil. You can look up copper wire sizes on line and find the resistance per unit length of such wire size.

Comment: Has the solenoid got to be able to hover at some intermediate position, or can it drive fully in? If the latter, then a short pulse of high current can be used to drive it home. Once home the better magnetic circuit can stay attracted with a much reduced current.

Comment: The stroke length is very important for solenoid design. All other things being equal, the force drops with the square of the gap, so lifting 40g 3mm takes about  1/100 the current of lifting it 3cm.

Comment: The mass of 40g to be lifted would be directly attached to the pin that's moved by the solenoid. The solenoid may move fully in/out. No imtermediate positions like holding it in the center or something.